# What is default GMail setting for: number of days of data to synchronize?

Tags: settings, gmail

Gmail allows to limit from how many last days it will synchronize the messages. E.g. from one day, two, etc.

What is the default setting? I think this is phone independent, but I ask about Samsung Galaxy S, and SII.

Comment: I think this may vary depending on the version of Gmail being used as well, actually, but I'm not positive.

Comment: Why the security tag? I can see how you could consider it a related to security somewhat but you don't mention it in the question.

Comment: If someone steals phone, this will be the amount of mail he can access

Comment: I thought that might be what you mean, but the attacker can always increase the value to whatever they want and access that many days of mail.

Comment: Yes, but the phone can be e.g. locked, giving enough time to change gmail password.

Comment: That's true but if the attacker can read your emails then that suggests he's already unlocked the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 days I believe, up till Gingerbread. I have Ice Cream Sandwich (ICS) and it's currently set at 30 days and I haven't changed it on my device since buying it so I suspect ICS has is set to 30 days as default.

If you look at: http://support.google.com/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=168499 (along with the other links I post below) you can see it mentions a 4 day sync, these posts seem to be referring to Gingerbread and below.

EDIT: After Googling around for a bit I think that 30 days is definitely just in ICS. A few people on various sites mention a 4 day sync which should have been Gingerbread and below. (Note that most of these sources are relatively poor but they mention the 4 day limit, hence why I've posted them)

- http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100122211939AAdHEs5
- http://androidforums.com/android-applications/30952-gmail-number-days-sync.html
- http://www.askmefast.com/What_does_sync_for_4_days_on_android_gmail_mean-qna370542.html

Comment: Which device you have?

Comment: A Nexus S, it's got ICS now. I'll edit my answer with some other stuff I've read.

Answer (score 3):

This default depends on your Android version.  The default setting used to 4 days but with ICS (might be honeycomb, I can't comfirm) it was changed to 30 days.

Comment: It for sure was not ICS :)